# SQLServerCE Problem with parameterized queries from .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce, parameterized-query

I am pulling the hair out of my head trying to figure this one out.

I can't make Parameterized queries to work in VB.Net, when I am using parameters.

From what I have found, using a parameter in a function, from .NET raises an error (see sample code). However, running the not working query in the Query Window in Visual studio works properly.

The error raised is:

> 25922 - The arguments for  function are not valid.

Info from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa256772%28SQL.80%29.aspx

**Sample Code:**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe

Public Class MiniDemo

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim cs As String = "Data Source=Inventory.sdf; Persist Security Info=False;"
        Dim db As New SqlCeConnection(cs)
        db.Open()


        ''#Using parameters works
        Dim cmd As SqlCeCommand = db.CreateCommand()

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO inventory_type (inv_type_id, inv_type_name) VALUES (@id, @name)"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", 1)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", "test")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()



        ''#Using parameters in functions does not work
        Dim cmd2 As SqlCeCommand = db.CreateCommand()

            ''#Broken on multiple lines for readability (built using string builders in real code)
        cmd2.CommandText = 
                     "SELECT 
                        inv_type_id, 
                        inv_type_name 
                      FROM
                        inventory_type 
                      WHERE 
                        ((@id IS NULL) OR (inv_type_id = @id)) AND 
                        ((@name IS NULL) OR (inv_type_name = @name))"

        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@id", 1)
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@name", "test") ''# Would not work with DBNull.Value either

        Dim da2 As New SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd2)
        Dim dt2 As New DataTable()
        da2.Fill(dt2)
        db.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I fail to see a material difference between your first and second samples.  What "function" are you referring to? .Fill()?

Comment: Are the @nom and @nome differences present in your production code? Or just in this example?

Comment: Just in this example, corrected

Comment: @Joel: the difference between the 2 is that the second fails because of the IS NULL (It gets converted to ISNULL(@id) behind the scenes, COALESCE(@id, 0) = 0) would yield the same error.

Comment: have you tried `inv_type_name = COALESCE(@name, inv_type_name)` (with DBNull.Value for the parameter value)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution for this problem.

Using a parameter in a function crashes if the DBType property of the parameter is not set:

**This will crash:**

```
    Dim cmd As SqlCeCommand = db.CreateCommand()

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COALESCE(@param1, @param2);"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", 1)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", "test")
    cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Using a parameter in a function will work if the DBType property of the parameter **is** set

**This will work:**

```
    Dim cmd As SqlCeCommand = db.CreateCommand()

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COALESCE(@param1, @param2);"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", 1).DbType = DbType.Int32
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", "test").DbType = DbType.String
    cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```