# Which string concatenation got more Performance in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, .net-3.5

I am working on an application targetted to .NET Framework CE and we have a lot of SQL Queries which are constructed by appending the data.

An example

```
      string SQL="insert into ERTLISTS (ERTNUM,ERTTYPE,ERT_Status,ERT_Items,ERTTo_Check," & _
                                            "ERT_Date,ERTe_Date,ERT_ID,Location_Count,TRS_Desc,QA_Cycle," & _
                                            "Due_Date,Next_WRK_Date,User_Freq) values (" & _
                 "" & CInt(strData(0)) & "," & _
                  "'" & strData(1) & "'," & _
                   "'" & strData(2) & "'," & _
                     "" & CInt(strData(3)) & "," & _
              "" & CInt(strData(4)) & "," & _
           "#" & CDate((strData(5).Substring(4, 2) & "/" & strData(5).Substring(2, 2) & "/" & strData(5).Substring(0, 2)).ToString()) & "#," & _
              "#" & CDate((strData(6).Substring(4, 2) & "/" & 
            strData(6).Substring(2, 2) &
     "/" & strData(6).Substring(0, 2)).ToString()) & "#," & _
         "" & CInt(strData(7)) & "," & _
         "" & CInt(strData(8)) & "," & _
         "'" & strData(9) & "'," & _
         "'" & strData(10) & "'," & _
        "#" & CDate((strData(11).Substring(4, 2) 
    & "/" & strData(11).Substring(2, 2) & "/" & strData(11).Substring(0, 2)).ToString()) & "#," & _
     "#" & CDate((strData(12).Substring(4, 2) 
    & "/" & strData(12).Substring(2, 2) & "/" & strData(12).Substring(0, 2)).ToString()) & "#," & _"#" & CDate((strData(13).Substring(4, 2) & "/" 
& strData(13).Substring(2, 2) & "/" 
& strData(13).Substring(0, 2)).ToString()) & "#)"
```

I also know about the StringBuilder , Is there any performance gain happen if I use Stringuilder ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-performance

Comment: @Steve thanks for your comment. In my case I am adding some values to a string. Using  only one variable. The eg shows using more than variable.  st1 += s;

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use a parameterized query?  That would avoid the need to concatenations and it would also avoid other problems too such as SQL-injection attacks and invalid characters in your data.

Comment: Code readability, in this case, would also be another perk of using parametrized queries. I would not be entirely thrilled if I had to modify some existing code and this is what I found.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I am using SQL CE and i believe that CE doesn't support parameteized Quries. Let me check it

Comment: Look at the accepted answer in this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836016/sqlserverce-problem-with-parameterized-queries-from-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836016/sqlserverce-problem-with-parameterized-queries-from-net). It shows an example of using parametrized queries with SQL CE.

Answer (score 0):

**String** type is immutable*(once it has been created, it cannot be
changed)*. There is no way to modify an olready created
string object. When you, for example, appending a character or another
string to a string, a new combined string is actually created every time.
**StringBuilder** is mutable and works much faster when you need to modify it's
content.

The `string builder` class provides a more efficient way to repeatedly add
bits on to a string. You provide it with an initial capacity (it grows
automatically, but will degrade performance if it grows too often). You can
add more bits of strings to it without the overhead of creating a new
object.

The performance difference will be too small to measure if you're only doing
a few concatenations, but if you're in a loop, building a big string then **StringBuilder** has a definite advantage.