# How can I do something like "STRING_AGG" in Sql Server Compact?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

everybody

I want to make something like STRING_AGG in Sql Server Compact.

For example, I want to flatten the code column in the table below:

```
+----+--------+  
| Id | Code   |  
+----+--------+    
| 1  | 256987 |   
| 1  | 256985 |   
| 1  | 356994 |  
+----+--------+
```

So I will get something like that:

```
+----+------------------------+   
| Id | Codes                  |   
+----+------------------------+      
| 1  | 256987, 256985, 356994 |   
+----+------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your best bet will be to do it using C# (string.Join)

Comment: Yes, i dit it in c# and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet will be to do it using C# ([`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join)).

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of ways to do this:

1: Using COALESCE

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE
(
Name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES
('Jim'),
('Tim'),
('Kim');

DECLARE @ReturnVar VARCHAR(256);

SELECT *
FROM @Tbl;

SELECT @ReturnVar = COALESCE(@ReturnVar + ', ', '') + Name
FROM @Tbl;

SELECT @ReturnVar;
```

2: Using XML

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE
(
Name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES
('Jim'),
('Tim'),
('Kim');

DECLARE @ReturnVar VARCHAR(256);

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + Name
                           FROM @Tbl
                           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Name;
```

You can find a bit more detail [here](https://lsdbtech.wordpress.com/2014/08/05/rows-to-string-2-ways/).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in Sql Server Compact we can't use DECLARE  or FOR XML PATH.

Comment: How are you firing your queries? Is it through a program or in a query window?

Comment: Through a program, finally I did it in c#  (string.Join), thanks!

Comment: Glad you solved it, you can also do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836016/sqlserverce-problem-with-parameterized-queries-from-net